# Why does printf print wrong values?

Tags: c, printing, type-conversion, printf

Why do I get the wrong values when I print an `int` using `printf("%f\n", myNumber)`?

I don't understand why it prints fine with `%d`, but not with `%f`. Shouldn't it just add extra zeros?

```
int a = 1;
int b = 10;
int c = 100;
int d = 1000;
int e = 10000;

printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e);   //prints fine
printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n", a, b, c, d, e);   //prints weird stuff
```

Comment: Integers are _not_ floating point values...

Comment: I understand that. But I wanted to know why it prints other stuff? Is there some type of overflowing? What is the reason behind printing what it does??

Comment: Is the typo in the second printf in your code too or just here? (%\n)

Comment: @Arnold: give that there are a few variables, my money's on typo.

Comment: -1 for yet another useless "why does this happen?" question with invalid code/undefined behavior.

Comment: gcc would warn you...if you enable warning. You should read c-faq, too. This kind of question has been answered long time ago.

Comment: @NedBatchelder You seem to be assuming that it's impossible to learn the basics of C on one's own. That's not true, and one has to make an effort.

Comment: C uses the GIGO (garbage in, garbage out) principle. Your second `printf()` statement is a fine example of exactly that.

Comment: @user3477950 I'm not sure why you tagged me, I haven't commented on this question at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when I use the wrong format specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864552/what-happens-when-i-use-the-wrong-format-specifier)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

well of course it prints the "weird" stuff. You are passing in `int`s, but telling `printf` you passed in `float`s. Since these two data types have different and incompatible internal representations, you will get "gibberish".

There is no "automatic cast" when you pass variables to a variandic function like `printf`, the values are passed into the function as the datatype they actually are (or upgraded to a larger compatible type in some cases).

What you have done is somewhat similar to this:

```
union {
    int n;
    float f;
} x;

x.n = 10;

printf("%f\n", x.f); /* pass in the binary representation for 10, 
                        but treat that same bit pattern as a float, 
                        even though they are incompatible */
```

Comment: *"There is no "automatic cast" when you pass variables to a variandic function"* - that's the key, and I think it bears repeating because it's quite subtle (if you are coming from a higher level language) and important.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print them as floats, you can cast them as float before passing them to the printf function.

```
printf("%f %f %f %f %f\n", (float)a, (float)b, (float)c, (float)d, (float)e);
```

Answer (score 3):

a, b, c, d and e aren't floats. printf() is interpreting them as floats, and this would print weird stuff to your screen.

Answer (score 2):

Using incorrect format specifier in `printf()` invokes `Undefined Behaviour`

For example:

```
 int n=1;
 printf("%f", n); //UB

 float x=1.2f;
 printf("%d", x); //UB

 double y=12.34;
 printf("%lf",y); //UB
```

Note: format specifier for `double` in `printf()` is `%f`.

Comment: ... then whats the specifier for 'float'?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is... inside `printf`. the following happens

```
if ("%f") {
 float *p = (float*) &a;
 output *p;  //err because binary representation is different for float and int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the way printf and variable arguments work is that the format specifier in the string e.g. "%f %f" tells the printf the type and thus the size of the argument. By specifying the wrong type for the argument it gets confused.

look at stdarg.h for the macros used to handle variable arguments

Answer (score 0):

For "normal" (non variadac functions with all the types specified) the compiler converts integer valued types to floating point types where needed.

That does not happen with variadac arguments, which are *always* passed "as is".

Comment: ...except when they're promoted to larger types.